# Only one editor of my MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

How can I configure MediaWiki so that I am the only one that will be able to edit content of MediaWiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to disable editing for non-logged in users, disable registration, and disable editing for regular users (Just in case someone is already registered)

Put this at the bottom of your LocalSettings.php

```
# Disable editing and account creation for regular and anonymous users
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit']              = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount']     = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit']           = false;
# Enable editing for yourself
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['edit']          = true;
# Hides the IP in the header
$wgShowIPinHeader                             = false;
```

For more about user rights, see [this manual page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUser_rights).